# im trying to display some code into a text area, i got it to work i just dont know how to get it to display my values JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

// i have this right now, im trying to figure out how i could print the values into a text area

onEvent("factorsof2", "click", function( ) {
```
var num = calculate();

````
function calculate(num) {
   ```
   var half = Math.floor(num / 2),
    ```
  str = '1',
    ```
  i, j;
````

````
num % 2 === 0 ? (i = 2, j = 1) : (i = 3, j = 2);
```
for (i; i <= half; i += j) {
````

```
        num % i === 0 ? str += ',' + i : false;
    }
```

```
str += ',' + num;
```

```
}
  setText("text_area3", "Your factors are: " + calculate(num));

});
```

Comment: Hi Kojou and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and check out the help center to guidelines. [How to format questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) is hard to find but really useful.

Comment: References to look up: [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)  to find elements, and [HTMLTextAreaElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) - text area elements have a `value` property you can set.